# How to dd shadow to highchart bars

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to add shadow behind highchart bars, so each column have a shadow that is filled with 100% height? Something like in the picture? Sorry if the shadow color is very gray.

This is a JsFiddle where I was able to add line seprator between the bars, but I really I need a shadow that represent each bar to 100% height

https://jsfiddle.net/wh67so0a/1/

```
     xAxis: {
   type: 'category',
       gridLineColor: 'red',
    gridLineWidth: 2,
    tickColor: 'green',
    tickLength: 20,
    tickWidth: 2,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'between'
       // categories: ['Client 1', 'Client 2', 'Client 3']
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotBands`:

```
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        plotBands: [{
            color: 'gray',
            from: -0.25,
            to: 0.25
        }, {
            color: 'gray',
            from: 0.75,
            to: 1.25
        }, {
            color: 'gray',
            from: 1.75,
            to: 2.25
        }]
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8a7wye13/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands